# List Modules in Craft System Report

Tags: plugins, modules

Plugins and application information is detailed in the system report. Is it possible to get my module to list itself there? And if not, is there somewhere else in the CMS to see modules that a registered and working?

Comment: You might want to consider making this a feature request on https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something that is built-in, probably the cleanest way would be to write a plugin that adds a Utility that lists your installed modules.

You can see *all* of the installed modules via:

```
Craft::$app->modules
```

...but keep in mind that this will include all of your plugins as well, since they are modules, too. You can exclude them by doing something like:

```
foreach (Craft::$app->modules as $module) {
    if (!is_a($module, Plugin::class)) {
    // This is some kind of module that isn't a plugin
    }
}
```

Note that this will include other things like the `yii\debug\Module` and even `craft\web\Application` too.

If you want to see just the *loaded* modules for the current request, you can do:

```
Craft::$app->loadedModules
```

(not all modules may be loaded for each request)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! It would be nice to be able to hook into the System Report page from a plugin to add additional information there, but this is a good option. I've also submitted a feature request as recommended by Brad.